Connect to OPC Ua Basic256Sha256 Security Policy with Python
I am trying to connect to an OPC Ua server to be able to read variables using a python code.
The Server and Client are on Windows Server 2022
This server has Security Policy: Basic256Sha256 , Message Security Mode: Sign and anonymous authentication.
I manage to connect and get variables values with Ua Expert
I have already tested several python libraries, but I can't get a script that works. I think it's because of the certificates but I don't understand everything about certificates.
in the example below:
from opcua import Client, ua

url = "opc.tcp://srvbeathcs01:44683/ABB/800xA/OPC/UA/Server"
client = Client(url)


client.set_security_string("Basic256Sha256,Sign,cert.pem,key.pem")

client.connect()
print(f"Connected to: {url}")

servicelevel_node = client.get_node("ns=2;b=ADwDSDdc1EO/1/EufyBvM8qrOcZ9hX9NnGQgzR8uGN1FbmVyZ2llRWxlYy5Db21wdGV1cjkudWludDI=")

servicelevel_node_value = servicelevel_node.get_value()
print(servicelevel_node_value)

client.disconnect()

How to get cert.pem and key.pem, is there a simple python script to generate them? I also have a server certificate in .der, do I have to do something with it?
I've try to generate the certificates with this script :
from OpenSSL import crypto

def generate_certificates():
    # Générer une clé privée
    key = crypto.PKey()
    key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)

    # Générer un certificat auto-signé
    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.set_version(2)
    cert.set_serial_number(1000)
    cert.get_subject().CN = "test.com"
    cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_notBefore(b'20240101000000Z')
    cert.set_notAfter(b'20250101000000Z')
    cert.set_pubkey(key)
    cert.sign(key, 'sha256')

    # Sauvegarder la clé privée et le certificat dans des fichiers
    with open("key.pem", "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key))

    with open("cert.pem", "wb") as cert_file:
        cert_file.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))

    print("Certificats generated!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_certificates()

The certificate are generated enter image description here
On the server side I receive the request and I can trust the certificate (test.com) in this exemple.
But I get thie error when trying to connect:
Received an error: MessageAbort(error:StatusCode(BadSecurityChecksFailed), reason:Could not verify security on OpenSecureChannel request.)
Received an error: MessageAbort(error:StatusCode(BadSecurityChecksFailed), reason:Could not verify security on OpenSecureChannel request.)
Protocol Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 101, in _run
    self._receive()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 121, in _receive
    self._call_callback(0, ua.UaStatusCodeError(msg.Error.value))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 129, in _call_callback
    raise ua.UaError(
opcua.ua.uaerrors._base.UaError: No future object found for request: 0, callbacks in list are dict_keys([1])
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x1a6fcaad5b0 state=cancelled>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 340, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 201, in clb
    response = struct_from_binary(ua.OpenSecureChannelResponse, future.result())
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 447, in result
    raise CancelledError()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python\Code.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 275, in connect
    self.open_secure_channel()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 335, in open_secure_channel
    result = self.uaclient.open_secure_channel(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 275, in open_secure_channel
    return self._uasocket.open_secure_channel(params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 209, in open_secure_channel
    response = clb.future.result(self.timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 458, in result
    raise TimeoutError()
TimeoutError

Can you help me?

Your certifiacte needs subject alternative name (SAN) which contains the application uri as urn field as first parameter and then either your clients ip or hostname.
If you switch to asyncua instead of the no longer maintained opcua library, there are methods to create the certificate. See: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-with-encryption.py


With the QuickOPC library (opclabs_quickopc package; disclaimer: I am the author of it), and by modifying the example from here , the following code can be used:

    # The QuickOPC package is needed. Install it using "pip install opclabs_quickopc".
    import opclabs_quickopc
    
    # Import .NET namespaces.
    from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA import *
    from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA.OperationModel import *
    
    # Instantiate the client object.
    client = EasyUAClient()
    
    # Obtain attribute data. By default, the Value attribute of a node will be read.
    try:
        attributeData = IEasyUAClientExtension.Read(client,
    UAEndpointDescriptor('opc.tcp://srvbeathcs01:44683/ABB/800xA/OPC/UA/Server'),
    UANodeDescriptor('ns=2;b=ADwDSDdc1EO/1/EufyBvM8qrOcZ9hX9NnGQgzR8uGN1FbmVyZ2llRWxlYy5Db21wdGV1cjkudWludDI='))
    except UAException as uaException:
        print('*** Failure: ' + uaException.GetBaseException().Message)
        exit()
    
    # Display results.
    print('Value: ', attributeData.Value)
    print('ServerTimestamp: ', attributeData.ServerTimestamp)
    print('SourceTimestamp: ', attributeData.SourceTimestamp)
    print('StatusCode: ', attributeData.StatusCode)


While it is also possible to specify the security policy, it should not be necessary - if that is the only policy the server exposes, it will be chosen automatically.
The QuickOPC will also generate the own (client-side) UA certificate automatically, so nothing needs to be done in this respect.
On the first runs, the code will also throw errors, because 1) the client does not trust the server, and 2) the server does not trust the client.
To resolve 1): After the faulty attempt, you will find a copy of the server certificate in the "OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" folder under the working directory. To make it trusted, copy the certificate to the "OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" folder.
To resolve 2): Consult the documentation to the server. There can be a user interface to make the rejected client certificate trusted, and/or similar procedure for copying the certificate in the file system is used.
Even if you use a different library, the procedures for establishing the certificate trust will most likely be similar (though the folder names may differ), so you can use that part.

Hello ZbynekZ and thank you for your answer.
I tried with your library, I managed to get the server certificate and moved it to the trust certificates on the client side.
But on the server side, I do not receive the client certificate.
I can receive it with UaExpert end trust it from the server-side application but with the code you provided I do not receive it.

Here is the error :
*** Failure: OPC UA service result - {BadCertificateChainIncomplete}. The certificate chain is incomplete.
--> {BadCertificateChainIncomplete}. Certificate chain validation incomplete.
--> {BadCertificateInvalid}. Certificate validation failed. NotSignatureValid: The signature of the certificate cannot be verified. Certificate chain validation incomplete.

The reason you do not see the client certificate on the server side because it has not yet gotten that far - it is still the client that does not accept the certificate. Is this a certificate from a CA (i.e. not self-signed by the server?). - such as enterprise CA, or UA GDS? In such case, it is also necessary to tell the client to trust the CA - for this there is the "UA Certificate Authorities" subfolder. If you like, this can be taken to our Online Forums (tech support).

Hi ZbynekZ,
I don't found the UA Certificates Authorihies subfolder
OPC Foundation
└── CertificateStores
├── MachineDefault
│   ├── certs
│   └── private
├── RejectedCertificates
│   └── certs
└── UA Applications
└── certs
Can you tell me wher to find it?

First you need to know whether the server has self-signed certificate, or a certificate from the CA. If it has self-signed certificate, the "UA Certificate Authorities" subfolder is not needed. I suspect that the server has CA-signed certificate, though. In such case the folder (and 'certs' subfolder') should be there (you can create it), and you need to place the CA certificate(s) there.
